# Typescript: How to reset properties value of a service that injected from DI

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a class

```
class Foo() {

}
```

and it has DI a class Bar()

```
class Foo() {
    constructor(
        bar: Bar
    ){}
}
```

to initialize Bar() properties value

```
class Foo() {
    constructor(
        bar: Bar
    ){}

    this.bar.name = "Hello World!";
    this.bar.number = "1234";
}
```

My question is how can I reset Bar() to clear every Bar() properties value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple assign to empty object `this.bar={}`